# Twilio API for WhatsApp

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I'm testing the Twilio API for WhatsApp, responding to incoming messages with TwiML.
In the request I can retrieve the sender's phone number, but is it also possible to retrieve the sender Whatsapp nick name?
It is also possible activate the typing indicators?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The inbound Twilio webhook for WhatsApp does not support the sender nickname and you can't set or receive typing indicators at the moment.